# Retain scroll on Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm displaying a list using lazy loading with some articles. When I go back to this after going to one of them the list scrolls to the top.

This apparently was fixed on Ionic 1 (https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/on-coming-back-from-details-to-list-page-the-scroll-position-goes-back-on-top-list-data-loaded-by-async-task/1432/10) but not sure how can I implement this using Ionic 3.

I could save position on `ionViewDidLeave` and get it on `ionViewDidEnter` but it should be an Ionic way